# How to correctly resize png images

Tags: php, png, gd

I use the following combination of functions

```
$img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
$dst_1 = imagecreate( $targ_w_1, $targ_h_1 );
imagecopyresampled($dst_1,$img_r,0,0,0,0,$targ_w_1,$targ_h_1,$size_test[0],$size_test[1]);
imagepng($dst_1, $final_source_1,9);
```

Final result comes with very low quality, as I understand imagepng max quality is 9. You cannot write 100 there. But still quality is very bad. maybe I use wrong functions to manipulate with image ? Any suggestions ?

1. original 220x220 image
   [image: original 220x220 image]
2. resized image to size 120x120
   [image: resized image to size 120x120]
3. resized image with the same size 220x220
   [image: resized image with the same size 220x220]

**SOLVED**

Comment: what are you trying to do re-size in a larger image or smaller ? You should know you cannot get a good quality if you try to make a larger image.

Comment: initial and final sizes of test image are the same. trying 0, and 9 as a compression but still bad result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with alpha . After I read Jaccos comment I went to google and found this

```
imagealphablending($dst_1, false);
imagesavealpha($dst_1,true);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($dst_1, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($dst_1, 0, 0,$targ_w_1, $targ_h_1, $transparent);
```

This peace of code must be put right after imagecreatetruecolor ad everything will be just fine :)

Comment: you should edit your original question instead of adding this as an answer

Comment: Problem is that If I have question without correct answer system starts to tell me "set bounty on this" etc.... I mean I want all questions to be solved. IF you want copy this and I mark your answer as solved.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no such thing as a quality setting in the PNG-format, nor in the underlying c-library. There is compression, but since PNG is a loss-less format, compressing the image does not degenerate the quality.

The compression setting of 9 gives the best compression (=smallest file size).

The issue you run into likely is that your destination image is created with `imagecreate()`; a paletted image.
You are more likely looking for [`imagecreatetruecolor()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php)

Comment: imagecreatetruecolor() created image with black background. While my initial background was transparent

Comment: @David, you should take a look at `imagesavealpha()` or the other documentation mentioning 'alpha' in their function name.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the [manual](http://php.net/imagepng). It has this to say on `imagepng()`'s `$quality` parameter:

> Compression level: from 0 (no compression) to 9.

So 9 seems to be the *worst* quality level. Try a lower setting.

Comment: The quality parameter is wrongly named. It should be named $compressionLevel, as it has nothing to do with quality.

Comment: @Jacco yup. Especially seeing as it works differently than the JPEG `$quality` parameter

Comment: both 0 or 9 do the same. image looks very bad

Comment: @David show an example then. Note however that if you want to enlarge a picture, it is impossible to keep the small original's quality

Comment: Example of image to see what happaned to it ? initial and final sizes of test image are the same

Comment: @David yeah, I mean an example of the image

Comment: @Jacco's suggestion is the right one then - your problem is a paletted image. There is help on the net on how to work with alpha transparency in truecolor images.